# Getting standard error associated with parameter estimates from scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit a curve to some data i have. The curves, for the most part, seem to fit very well. For some reason, pcov = inf when i print it off.

What i really need is to calculate the error associated with the parameters i'm fitting, and am not sure how exactly to do this even if it does give me the covariance matrix.

The model being fit to is:

```
def intensity(x,R_out,R_in,K_in,K_out,a,b,c):
    K_in,K_out = abs(0.0),abs(K_out)
    if x<=R_in:
        return 2*R_out*(K_out*np.sqrt(1-x**2/R_out**2)-
                (K_out-0.0)*np.sqrt(R_in**2/R_out**2-x**2/R_out**2)) + c
    elif x>=R_in and x<=R_out:
        return K_out*2*R_out*np.sqrt(1-x**2/R_out**2) + c
    elif x>R_out:
        return c

intensity_vec = np.vectorize(intensity)



def intensity_vec_self(x,R_out,R_in,K_in,K_out,a,b,c):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i]=intensity_vec(x[i],R_out,R_in,K_in,K_out,a,b,c)
    return y
```

and there are 400 data points, i can put that on here if you think it will help.

To summarize, i can't get `curve_fit` to print off my `pcov` and need help as to figure out why and if i can get it to do so.

Also, if it is a quick explanation i would like to know how to use the `pcov` array to attain the errors associated with my fit.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The variance of parameters are the diagonal elements of the variance-co variance matrix, and the standard error is the square root of it. `np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`

Regarding getting `inf`, see and compare these two examples:

```
In [129]:
import numpy as np
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1)
ydata = y + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(xdata))
popt, pcov = so.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
[ inf  inf  inf  inf]
```

And:

```
In [130]:

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
ydata = y + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(xdata))
popt, pcov = so.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
[ 0.11097646  0.11849107  0.05230711]
```

In this extreme example, `d` has no effect on the function `func`, hence it will be associated with variance of `+inf`, or in another word, it can be just about any value. Removing `d` from `func` will get what will make sense.

In reality, if parameters are of very different scale, say:

```
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    #return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c + d*1e-10
```

You will also get `inf` due to float point overflow/underflow.

In your case, I think you never used `a` and `b`. So it is just like the first example here.

Comment: I get what you are saying about having those extra parameters in the equation and have removed them from my code. Unfortunately, i am left with the same issue. printing pcov returns 'inf'

Comment: i dont know why it didn't work earlier, but your suggestion is fixing the issue now. I must have made some mistake earlier when i applied the change. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the square root of the variance the standard deviation, not the standard error?