# Using a guess with scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-analysis

I have a function that I want to curve fit with knowing the error of the curve fit. I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to do this but am running into problem. Right now my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

pi = np.pi
sqrt = np.sqrt
mean = np.mean

A = 1
T_2 = 100
nu_0 = 10
phi_0 = 0
n = .001
nu_s = 500
T = 1000

t = np.linspace(0, T, num = (nu_s*T))

def S_n(A,t,T_2,nu_0,phi_0,n,nu_s,T):
    return (A/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-t/T_2)*np.cos(2*pi*nu_0*t+phi_0)

S = S_n(A,t,T_2,nu_0,phi_0,n,nu_s,T) + np.random.normal(0, n, nu_s*T)

guess = np.array([A,T_2,nu_0,phi_0,n,nu_s,T])
print guess

popt, pcov = curve_fit(S_n,t,S, guess)
print popt
perr = sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
print perr
```

Which gives me infinite error. I'm not sure I am doing my guess correctly because in the equation, everything remains constant except t, so do I leave t out of my guess because it is no longer an array because t is a sequence. When I leave t out of the guess, which I am doing here I receive values for each variable to be far from the values I give initially with infinite error. If I include t in the guess, then I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't take the order of the parameters to `curve_fit` into account:

> Definition:  curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kw)
>
> Docstring:
>   Use non-linear least squares to fit a function, f, to data.
>
> Assumes `ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> f : callable
>      The model function, f(x, ...).  It must take the independent
>      variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as
>      separate remaining arguments.

If you make a function:

```
def Sm(t, A,T_2,nu_0,phi_0,n,nu_s,T):
    return S_n(A, t, T_2,nu_0,phi_0,n,nu_s,T)
```

(notice the order of the first 2 parameters has changed)
and pass that to `curve_fit`, it will work.

It is probably more pythonic to clean your original function though:

```
def S_n(t, A, T_2, nu_0, phi_0, n, nu_s, T):
    return (A/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-t/T_2)*np.cos(2*pi*nu_0*t+phi_0)

S = S_n(t, A, T_2, nu_0, phi_0, n, nu_s, T) + np.random.normal(0, n, nu_s*T)
```

Then you can pass `S_n` to `curve_fit` unchanged, as well as `S` and `guess`.

To be clear, the following code produces the desired fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def S_n(t, amplitude, sigma,freq0,phase):
    return (amplitude/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-t/sigma)*np.cos(2*np.pi*freq0*t+ phase)

amplitude = 1
sigma = 100
freq0 = 10
phase = 0
n = .001
sample_freq = 500
period = 1000

t = np.linspace(0, period, num = (sample_freq*period))
S = S_n(t, amplitude, sigma,freq0,phi_0) + np.random.normal(0, n, sample_freq*period)

guess = np.array([amplitude, sigma, freq0, phase ])
print guess
popt, pcov = curve_fit(S_n,t,S, guess)
print popt
print(np.all(np.isfinite(pcov)))
# output
[  1 100  10   0]
[  1.00000532e+00   1.00000409e+02   1.00000000e+01  -1.49076430e-05]
True
```

Comment: You're saying to add the def Sm separate of everything else then have curve_fit(S_n,t,Sm,guess)? This isn't including the random noise that I need. Or did you mean to have curve_fit(Sm,t,S,guess)? If that, then do I change my guess?

Comment: @jakeowen do the last part: call `curve_fit(Sm,t,S,guess)` and leave everything else. You can leave the `guess` as is: it was in the correct order. Basically `curve_fit` will call the model function, `Sm` in this case, with the 2nd parameter supplied to it, `t`, as the model function's first argument. The `guess`, will be added as extra arguments in its call to the model function.

Comment: It is still giving me the same problem. When I run it like that with curve_fit(Sm,t,S,guess) the output is [  2.28727542e+00  -8.16926439e+01   4.39912861e+03   1.04075178e+06
   1.00000000e-03   5.00000000e+02   1.00000000e+03]
[ inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf].

Comment: @jakeowen, join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69005/conversation-between-oliver-w-and-jakeowen)

Comment: @Oliver_W. I'm realizing there is still a problem with this. When I run it since we talked last, I realized the approximate parameters returned are still far off from what I would expect. It is returning [  5.17862739e+01  -4.38392698e+04  -5.20188972e+02   5.64603965e+00
   1.00000000e-03   5.00000000e+02   1.00000000e+03]
where I would expect the returns to be about [1,100,10,0,.001,500,1000]. The last 3 variables are as expected, but the first 4 are very far off returning big errors. This shouldn't be expected because the noise added is very small.

Comment: @jakeowen, it is my guess that you have changed the order of some variables again. I've updated the post to show the exact code that I'm running and it works fine.

Comment: @Oliver_W. I also need the error though, when I'm using what you have right now and add either print(pcov) or perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)) print(perr) I receive infinite errors.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just still a little confused on what exactly you are doing, I'm also trying to plot everything too to show the difference in the fit and noise data and what is plotted does not look at all like the curve. It is now just a linear plot.

Comment: @jakeowen that's because your model has 3 parameters that are not being used at all: `n, nu_s, T`. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25235710/2476444) too (I upvoted it). If you get rid of those 3 unused parameters (also in the `guess`) then pcov will return finite values. I have changed my answer to reflect the variables you *are* using and to give them more descriptive titles.