# How to estimate error propagation on regressed function from covariance matrix using scipy.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, propagation

I need a hand with something. I'm using curve_fit from SciPy to fit a curve with three parameters. Now, when I use it, I get this thing called `pcov`, which I know is the covariance matrix. But here's the thing: can I use `pcov` to figure out how much my predictions might be off?

I know I can calculate the error between the real data and the fitted curve, but can I somehow use `pcov` to get that error variance directly for a new data point I'm predicting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting standard error associated with parameter estimates from scipy.optimize.curve\_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234996/getting-standard-error-associated-with-parameter-estimates-from-scipy-optimize-c)

Comment: See also the SciPy manual: "The estimated approximate covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters, use perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)). Note that the relationship between cov and parameter error estimates is derived based on a linear approximation to the model function around the optimum [1]. When this approximation becomes inaccurate, cov may not provide an accurate measure of uncertainty." https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 1):

Provided your model is continuous and smooth and the the covariance matrix is a good approximation (see `@Nick ODell` comments), you can use [first order error propagation method](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/97374?ln=en) to estimate first order error on your regression wrt parameters covariance.

Lets say you have the following dataset and model:

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd
from scipy import optimize, stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b / (x**2 + 1) + c

np.random.seed(123456)
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
p = (3, 2, 1)
y = model(x, *p)
s = np.full_like(y, 0.15)
n = s * np.random.normal(size=y.size)
y += n

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, y, sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True)
# (array([3.01353034, 1.92219962, 1.01378869]),
#  array([[ 3.05357145e-03,  7.04390835e-11, -6.30392759e-11],
#         [ 7.04390835e-11,  3.92488970e-02, -3.02487191e-02],
#         [-6.30392759e-11, -3.02487191e-02,  2.44373750e-02]]))
```

We define the error function as follow:

```
def variance(model, x, p, Cp):
    
    def proxy(q):
        return model(x, *q)
    
    def projection(J):
        return J @ Cp @ J.T
    
    Jp = nd.Gradient(proxy)(p)
    Cy = np.apply_along_axis(projection, 1, Jp)
    
    return Cy
```

We can then estimate the curve:

```
xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
yhat = model(xlin, *popt)
```

And assess the confidence interval:

```
alpha = 0.01
z = stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.)
Cy = variance(model, xlin, popt, pcov)
sy = np.sqrt(Cy)
ci = z * sy
```

It graphically leads to:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(x, y, marker=".")
axe.plot(xlin, yhat)
axe.plot(xlin, yhat + ci, "--", color="k")
axe.plot(xlin, yhat - ci, "--", color="k")
axe.grid()
```

[image]

And gives an envelope where the curve would be found (if smooth and continuous) using parameters first order variation wrt their uncertainty.